# globally replace login_url of login_required in django

Tags: python, django

I'm using django 1.6.

Now I'm using the `@login_reqired()` decorator for the view function.

But my `login_url` is not the default, so now I have to pass that parameter manually as below:

```
@login_required(login_url=reverse('erp:index:login'))
def index(request, *args, **kwargs):
    return render(request, 'erp/index/index.html', kwargs)
```

Is there any way to replace it globally, so that I can use `@login_required` merely to redirect to my correct login view?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure, just put it in your settings as described in [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.decorators.login_required):

> If the user isn’t logged in, redirect to settings.LOGIN_URL, passing the current absolute path in the query string.
>
> The settings.LOGIN_URL also accepts view function names and named URL patterns. This allows you to freely remap your login view within your URLconf without having to update the setting.

So set your `LOGIN_URL` to whatever you want the URL or view name to be:

```
LOGIN_URL = 'erp:index:login'
```